Issues with permissions on macOS and resetting these permissions
I have some issues on macOS Ventura about permissions
In the same folder I can open some files say with SKIM for PDF files.
But not others even though they all have rw-r--r--@
I suspect it happened after some crash and the ones I cannot open are the newly downloaded!
I tried:
sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / 'id -u'

And then I got:

Error: -69841: Permissions reset on user home directory failed

So I did:
chflags -R nouchg *

It went through though with some “permission denied” on Google Drives:
chflags: Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-geotrycs@gmail.com/.tmp: Permission denied
 also on
chflags: Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/DataVaults: Operation not permitted

(I'm not using apple.mail anyway!)
So, I thought those are not a problem
I redid:
sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / 'id -u'

I get the same error.
And then:

Error: -69841: Permissions reset on user home directory failed

Here is the full result of first aid:
Running First Aid on “Container disk1”

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying storage system
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the encryption key structures.
error: object (oid 0xb39c64d7a6841da9): o_cksum (0x136a758e9b9e011d) is invalid for object
error: object (oid 0xb39c64d7a6841da9): o_type invalid, o_type 0x51080fd4 should be 0x72656373
error: object (oid 0xb39c64d7a6841da9): o_subtype invalid, o_subtype 0x1e30fc98 should be 0x0
warning: volume keybag (44693556+1): block range isn't a valid keybag, skipping checks
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 1 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2024-12-04-100040.local)
warning: inode (id 331086936): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: snapshot fsroot / file key rolling / doc-id tree corruptions are not repaired; they'll go away once the snapshot is deleted
warning: inode (id 334511517): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334519897): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334532660): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334535849): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334536221): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334541822): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334542255): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334542473): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334546170): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334546437): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334572374): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334574902): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334576375): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334578306): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334578629): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334579177): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334585561): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334606267): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334606369): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334607641): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334609862): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334707016): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334708514): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334709944): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334714110): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334746304): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334746987): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334764204): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334766417): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334772054): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334772806): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334774172): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334774684): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334775101): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334777236): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334777571): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334781153): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334838464): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334862808): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334863005): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334863320): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334863609): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334866869): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334868988): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334869518): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334869742): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334874378): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334874958): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
warning: inode (id 334875136): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file
Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones.
Checking the document ID tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s2.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s2 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s3.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s3 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s4.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s4 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s5.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 1 (com.apple.os.update-F06D7F99AEB01CD2BD3B8D9913FAABC40F1408DCAB6C2457B2220D28CED04850)
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the file extent tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s6.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s6 appears to be OK.
Verifying allocated space.
warning: container keybag (211137419+1): UUID 6D9308FC-4F82-4B2B-B34B-BA4DB900F942 of entry 0 (tag 3) does not reference any volume
Performing deferred repairs.
warning: need to clear bsd flags (0x20) in inode (object-id 331086936)
Skipped 60/60 repairs of this type in total.
warning: found orphan/invalid xattr (id 331086936, name com.apple.decmpfs)
Skipped 60/60 repairs of this type in total.
The container /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK.
Storage system check exit code is 0.

Operation successful.


UPDATE: I forgot you said you're on Ventura and since I can't remember if my previous answer works for Ventura, I'm updating with a simpler, safer solution.
Run diskutil resetUserPermissions / $(id -u) on the command line. It'll take a little bit to run through everything, but if successful, you'll be running like it's brand new.
That's all, let me know if it works. I've never had a case where I couldn't fix the permissions and ACLs. It's a total headache at times, but there's nothing that can't be resolved.
On a side note, I'd recommend not tweaking Apple's security settings either on the command line or in Recovery Mode. There are reasons and times to do so, but you have to use with caution. If you disabled protections to set custom permissions and made issues worse, the script above should resolve this.

Thanks. Do you know if there is any chance of not being able to repair Permissions and ACL at all, for example, if the disk is damaged? Also, I was wondering what are the required set of passwords (not just the admin one) you need when you restart from Recovery ... like the long security password etc. Should I try to gather all those before doing anything? (I know it is another problem). The thing is last time I did a Safe reboot it was quite instable (that's why I thought of damaged disk)

I also saw this Linc Davis answer: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5275515?sortBy=rank

Also, I found somewhere that copying the document which cannot be opened to another folder could work ... and it did! What does this mean for the permissions/ACL or disk?
